# Typeahead.js Suggest Not Rendering Properly

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js

I am using the [Typeahead.js](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md) plugin. I am trying to create custom templates for the suggestions. Currently, I have the following:

```
var suggestions = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  remote: '/api/suggests?querytext=%QUERY'
});
suggestions.initialize();

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input.typeahead').typeahead(
    { minLength: 3 },
    {
      name: 'suggestions',
      source: suggestions.ttAdapter(),
      templates: {
        suggestion: function(data) {
          var str = '';
          str += '<div>Result: ';
          // if suggestion is a Customer show 1 icon and the Name
          // elseif suggestion is a Product show a different icon and the name          
          str += '</div>';
          return str;
        }
      }
    }
  );
});
```

The suggestions are popping up. However, I am unable to actually get the property values from inside of my results. When Bloodhound requests the suggestions, I get a result set back that looks like this:

```
{
  "Results":[
    {
      "Type":"Customer",
      "Id":5,
      "Name":"Bill",
      "LastUpdated":"01-01-2015"
    },
    {
      "Type":"Customer",
      "Id":135,
      "Name":"Billows",
      "LastUpdated":"01-02-2015",
    },
    {
      "Type":"Product",
      "Id":241,
      "Name":"Bill Check",
      "LastUpdate":"01-04-2015"
    }
  ],
  "TotalResults":3,
  "TotalCustomers":2,
  "TotalProducts":1
}
```

How do I get the individual `Name` and `Type` values for a single suggestion in the template so I can render it properly?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var suggestions = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {
        url: '/api/suggests?querytext=%QUERY',
        filter: function(list) {
            var suggestions = list.Results;
            return $.map(suggestions, function(suggestion) { return { Type: suggestion.Type, Id: suggestion.Id, Name: suggestion.Name, LastUpdated: suggestion.LastUpdated }; });
        }
    }
});
suggestions.initialize();

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input.typeahead').typeahead(
            { minLength: 3 },
            {
                name: 'suggestions',
                source: suggestions.ttAdapter(),
                templates: {
                    suggestion: function (data) {
                        var str = '';
                        str += '<div>Result: ';
                        // get value by data.Type data.Name
                        str += '</div>';
                        return str;
                    }
                }
            }
    );
});
```

Comment: In `0.10.5` typeahead only accepts a single parameter